# delete and insert in random position in std::list

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to delete random position from stl::list. since List does not have random access iterator I was wondering how I could do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <random>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
  std::random_device dev;
  std::mt19937 rng(dev());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist6(1,99); // distribution in range [1, 99]
  std::list<int> myList;
  for(int i = 0; i<100; ++i)
  {
      myList.push_back(i);
  }
  auto it = myList.begin();
  for(int i =0; i<100/2; ++i) //remove 50 item.
  {
      //move iterator to begin + randrom number.
      //call erase with the iterator (it = myList.erase(it))
  }
  auto iter = myList.begin();
  for(int i = 0; i<100/2; ++i)
  {
     //move iterator to random position
     //insert the value of i to that location. myList.insert(iter,i)
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using a list if you want random access?

Comment: You start at the beginning of the list and start counting as you iterate forward. If you already have an iterator and know the "index" matching the iterator you can increment or decrement the iterator to move the iterator the difference. Or you can start at the beginning or ending, depending on which is closer to the new position. `std::advance` may be useful.

Comment: A piece from the creator of C++ on an experiment with this very use case: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::advance` or `std::next` to advance an iterator an arbitrary number of positions. For an iterator over a linked list, this will take time linear on the number of positions being advanced (so chances are pretty good that for a task like this, you shouldn't be using a linked list, but such is life).

```cpp
  using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type>;

  for(int i =0; i<100/2; ++i)
  {
      Dist dist(1, myList.size());
      auto iter = std::next(myList.begin(), dist(rng));
      myList.erase(iter);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i<100/2; ++i)
  {
     Dist dist(1, myList.size());
     auto iter = std::next(myList.begin(), dist(rng));
     myList.insert(iter, i);
 }
```

When/if you decide to use a container that supports random-access iterators, `std::next` and `std::advance` will automatically use their ability to add an offset to the iterator in constant time rather than the linear-time repeated-increment used for a forward iterator or bidirectional iterator, so this code will continue to work (and most likely get quite a bit faster) if you change `myList` to an `std::vector` or `std::deque`.

Comment: You should add position checks; they will blindly shoot past end.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: ...or better still, only generate values that are valid.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Doesn't vector invalidate iterator after erasing? How can this be done with vector without messing up the iterator?

Comment: It invalidates that particular iterator, but at least as the code is written here, as soon as we delete the element, we discard that iterator anyway, and create a new iterator on the next iteration of the loop.